# Power Series Solution to $y''+x^2y'+xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I've been trying to solve this one for a while and haven't had any success. Since I'm not exactly sure how formatting works, I figured I'd just scan what I have done so far and post it.

I'm not sure what to do with the terms that come before the summation, like $c_{-2}$ and $c_{-1}$. Can I ignore them after using them to solve for the other terms, given the assumption that the power series we use for $y$ starts at $n=0$?

[Let me know if it isn't legible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2lIm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''+x^2y'+xy=0$$
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$$
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_nn(n-1)x^{n-2}+x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nnx^{n-1}+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=0$$
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_nn(n-1)x^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nnx^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n+1}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_{n-1}(n-1)x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{n-1}x^{n}=0$$
$$c_0x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_{n-1}(n)x^{n}=0$$
$$c_0x+2c_2+6c_3x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty( c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+c_{n-1}n)x^{n}=0$$
Hence for $n \ge 2$:
$$(c_0+6c_3)x+2c_2=0$$
$$ c_{n+2}=-\dfrac {nc_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$
Or more simply for $n \ge 1$::
$$c_2=0$$
$$ c_{n+2}=-\dfrac {nc_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$
Is this what you have ?

Comment: OH, I see now. That's almost what I have. I changed the index for one of the summations to $n=-1$ instead of $n=1$, which is what threw me off. I did get the same result for $c_{n+2}$, so at least that much is reassuring. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately the recurrence formula is far from being simple. So I think you will not be able to go that far from here. @shadycrane

Comment: Fortunately for me, in these circumstances my professor allows us to simply list the first 6 terms of the series and then find $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ from there.

Comment: Oh I see then you can calculate the first terms of the series. @shadycrane.  +1 for your attempt